# string mattcher regex needed

Tags: java, regex, string

I have java code with matcher to find number of occurence in string using mattcher.find method.

following is my code

```
String text = "INCLUDES(ABC) EXCLUDES(ABC) EXCLUDES(ABC) INCLUDES(EFG) INCLUDES(IJK)";

String patternString = "INCLUDES(.)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

int count = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
    count++;
    System.out.println("found: " + count + " : "
            + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" - " +text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
}
```

which returns output as

```
found: 1 : 0 - 9
 - INCLUDES(
found: 2 : 42 - 51
 - INCLUDES(
found: 3 : 56 - 65
 - INCLUDES(
```

Instead of i want Regex to find and return number of occurrences as INCLUDES(*)

any solution is appriciated. expected output should be loop printing values

```
INCLUDES(ABC)
INCLUDES(EFG)
INCLUDES(IJK)
```

Comment: Do you just want the output for INCLUDES? And what is the expected output?

Comment: Is this just missing a * after the . maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct. You are just capturing a single character inside the bracket, and hence your regex will fail.

Try using this: -

```
"\\w+\\(.*?\\)"
```

And then get `group(0)`, or just `group()`: -

```
String text = "INCLUDES(ABC) EXCLUDES(ABC) EXCLUDES(ABC) INCLUDES(ABC) INCLUDES(ABC)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\(.*?\\)").matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```